# converter stripe to be able to be used in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to take advantage of the stripes payment system inside of my app. I am following along their guide, and I ran into an issue with their server-side code example. the code is only followed in these languages curl Ruby Python PHP Node Java Go .NET. and I am using swift. I am not sure if there is a swift conversion, or if I have to use these languges? if so, How would I go about using it?

Answer (score 0):

Server side swift is not supported by Stripe. You can find the list of supported languages here: https://stripe.dev/

If you still wish to use Swift, you can possibly create your own HTTP requests to interact with the Stripe API, although I don't recommend this as it's probably more effort than it's worth. See the docs for using curl: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=curl

Comment: do you think curl is the easiest?

Comment: I think not using server side Swift is the easiest.

Comment: I have been trying to find tutorials online, but I can't find anything. I am trying to use firebase as my server. I would think that would be simple to use with swift

Comment: Firebase has a guide on how to use Stripe with it, but it requires using Node.js: https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments